# visual studio code unit test discovery frequency setting

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-code, pytest

When I'm updating my existing unit tests, Visual Studio code drops a status bar from the top letting me know that it could not correctly discover unit tests every time I save the file. This is expected since I'm actively typing so everything is not working python.

[image]

Have I configured something incorrectly? Is there some way to tell visual studio to chill out on the unit test discovery?

Of course, I can simply hit the "close" button, but this is extremely distracting.

Comment: I've decided the solution is to simply save less. saving every 45 seconds or so is just as useful as the excessive save every 5 seconds or so. this will probably save my fingers a bit of wear and tear as well. If there's a way to "close" a question in SO, let me know and I'll do that

Comment: Just delete it I guess ;)

Answer (score 0):

Disable Live Unit Test running on the background.

[image: Disable Live Test Execution]

Under Test->Test Settings-> uncheck 'Keep Test Execution Engine Running'. I am using VS 2017 & VS 2015.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but my question specifically pertains to Visual Studio Code, not Visual Studio. VS Code doesn't have the same test menu.